Create a history table and keep track of all the updates to a document
I have a NestJS application that uses mongoose and MongoDB. I need to capture all changes/versions of this document so that I can display this as a history of the document, what changes were made by whom etc. However, there is no out-of-box solution that worked.
I tried the following plugins:

mongoose-history
mongoose-history-trace
ts-patch-mongoose

Since mongoose-history is archived on GitHub I tried to modify that and couldn't fix it as the issue was that I couldn't establish the connection with DB.
This is where I am at now.
history-modal.ts
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

interface MetadataOption {
  key: string;
  schema?: mongoose.SchemaDefinitionProperty<undefined, any>;
  value?: (
    original: any,
    d: any,
    callback?: (err: any, data: any) => void,
  ) => any;
}

export interface HistoryOptions {
  customCollectionName: any;
  customDiffAlgo?: any;
  diffOnly: any;
  indexes?: any[];
  historyConnection?: mongoose.Connection;
  metadata?: MetadataOption[];
}

const historyModels: Record<string, mongoose.Model<any>> = {};

export function HistoryModel(
  collectionName: string,
  options?: HistoryOptions,
): mongoose.Model<any> {
  const indexes = options?.indexes;
  const historyConnection = options?.historyConnection;
  const metadata = options?.metadata;

  const schemaObject: mongoose.SchemaDefinition = {
    t: { type: Date, required: true },
    o: { type: String, required: true },
    d: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true },
  };

  if (metadata) {
    metadata.forEach((m: MetadataOption) => {
      schemaObject[m.key] = m.schema || {
        type: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {} },
      };
    });
  }

  if (!historyModels[collectionName]) {
    const schema = new mongoose.Schema(schemaObject, {
      id: true,
      versionKey: false,
    });

    if (indexes) {
      indexes.forEach((idx) => {
        schema.index(idx);
      });
    }

    if (historyConnection) {
      historyModels[collectionName] = historyConnection.model(
        collectionName,
        schema,
        collectionName,
      );
    } else {
      historyModels[collectionName] = mongoose.model(
        collectionName,
        schema,
        collectionName,
      );
    }
  }

  return historyModels[collectionName];
}

export function historyCollectionName(
  collectionName: string,
  customCollectionName?: string,
): string {
  return customCollectionName || `${collectionName}_history`;
}

mongoose-history.ts
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {
  HistoryModel,
  historyCollectionName,
  HistoryOptions,
} from './history-model';
import * as async from 'async';

export async function historyPlugin(
  schema: mongoose.Schema,
  options?: HistoryOptions,
) {
  const customCollectionName = options?.customCollectionName;
  const customDiffAlgo = options?.customDiffAlgo;
  const diffOnly = options?.diffOnly;
  const metadata = options?.metadata;

  // Clear all history collection from Schema
  schema.statics.historyModel = function () {
    return HistoryModel(
      historyCollectionName(this.collection.name, customCollectionName),
      options,
    );
  };

  // Clear all history documents from history collection
  schema.statics.clearHistory = function (callback: (err: any) => void) {
    const History = HistoryModel(
      historyCollectionName(this.collection.name, customCollectionName),
      options,
    );
    History.deleteMany({}, function (err: any) {
      callback(err);
    });
  };

  // Save original data
  schema.post('init', function () {
    if (diffOnly) {
      this._original = this.toObject();
    }
  });

  function setMetadata(
    original: any,
    d: any,
    historyDoc: any,
    callback: (err?: any) => void,
  ) {
    async.each(
      metadata,
      (m, cb) => {
        if (typeof m.value === 'function') {
          if (m.value.length === 3) {
            /** async function */
            m.value(original, d, function (err: any, data: any) {
              if (err) return cb(err);
              historyDoc[m.key] = data;
              cb();
            });
          } else {
            historyDoc[m.key] = m.value(original, d);
            cb();
          }
        } else {
          historyDoc[m.key] = d ? d[m.value as keyof typeof d] : null;
          cb();
        }
      },
      callback,
    );
  }

  // Create a copy when insert or update, or a diff log
  schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    let historyDoc: any = {};

    if (diffOnly && !this.isNew) {
      const original = this._original;
      delete this._original;
      const d = this.toObject();
      const diff: Record<string, any> = { _id: d._id };

      for (const k in d) {
        if (customDiffAlgo) {
          const customDiff = customDiffAlgo(k, d[k], original[k]);
          if (customDiff) {
            diff[k] = customDiff.diff;
          }
        } else {
          if (String(d[k]) !== String(original[k])) {
            diff[k] = d[k];
          }
        }
      }

      historyDoc = createHistoryDoc(diff, 'u');
    } else {
      const d = this.toObject();
      const operation = this.isNew ? 'i' : 'u';
      historyDoc = createHistoryDoc(d, operation);
    }

    saveHistoryModel(this, historyDoc, next);
  });

  // Listen on updateOne
  schema.pre('updateOne', function (next) {
    processUpdate.call(this, next);
  });

  // Listen on findOneAndUpdate
  schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
    processUpdate.call(this, next);
  });

  // Create a copy on remove
  schema.pre('deleteOne', async function (next) {
    const doc = await this.findOne(this.getFilter()).lean();
    processRemove.call(doc, next);
  });

  schema.pre('findOneAndDelete', function (next) {
    this.findOne(this.getFilter())
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc) {
          processRemove.call(doc, next);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      })
      .catch(next);
  });

  function createHistoryDoc(d: any, operation: string) {
    const { __v, ...doc } = d;

    return {
      t: new Date(),
      o: operation,
      d: doc,
    };
  }

  function saveHistoryModel(
    instance: any,
    historyDoc: any,
    next: (err?: any) => void,
  ) {
    if (metadata) {
      setMetadata(instance._original, instance, historyDoc, (err) => {
        if (err) return next(err);

        const historyModel = HistoryModel(
          historyCollectionName(instance.collection.name, customCollectionName),
          options,
        );

        const history = new historyModel(historyDoc);
        history.save();
      });
    } else {
      const historyModel = HistoryModel(
        historyCollectionName(instance.collection.name, customCollectionName),
        options,
      );

      const history = new historyModel(historyDoc);
      history.save();
    }
    next();
  }

  function processUpdate(next: (err?: any) => void) {
    const d = this.getUpdate().$set || this.getUpdate();
    const historyDoc = createHistoryDoc(d, 'u');

    saveHistoryModel(this, historyDoc, next);
  }

  function processRemove(doc: any, next: (err?: any) => void) {
    const d = doc.toObject();
    const historyDoc = createHistoryDoc(d, 'r');

    saveHistoryModel(this, historyDoc, next);
  }
}

Here is a Task Document:
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export type TaskDocument = HydratedDocument<Task>;

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Task {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'My task', description: 'The task name' })
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    example: 'My task description',
    description: 'The task description',
  })
  @Prop({ required: true })
  description: string;

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'true', description: 'Is this task complete' })
  @Prop({ default: false })
  complete: boolean;

  @ApiProperty({
    example: 'james.bond@gmail.com',
    description: 'The email of the user who created',
  })
  @Prop({ required: true })
  created_by: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    example: 'james.bond@gmail.com',
    description: 'The email of the user who updated',
  })
  @Prop({ required: true })
  updated_by: string;

}

export const TaskSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Task);
TaskSchema.plugin(historyPlugin, {
  customCollectionName: 'task_history',
  diffOnly: true,
  metadata: [],
});

The error that I get is:

MongooseError: Operation `task_history.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

There is a task_history table. I created it. Is there any solution that I am not aware of? Is there another way to achieve this?
